# Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.1 - Tip Calculator Crashed Immediately

Tags: ios, swift, calculator

So I'm pretty new to Swift. I'm building a tip calculator in Swift and I found a tutorial online and modified it. It was a Swift 3 tutorial however, so I don't know how well it translates to Swift 4.2 from Swift 3 and latest iOS version as well, but it was working until I tried added a feature that would allow me to split the bill. Now the whole app just gives me a white screen and no runtime errors.

I've tried to implement the splitting the bill feature two ways including using a switch case (currently in the code), and asking the user to input a number and neither way seemed to work.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var billAmountField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var tipSelector: UISegmentedControl!

    @IBOutlet weak var userTipAmountField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var tipAmountField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var totalAmountField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var userSplitSelector: UISegmentedControl!

    @IBOutlet weak var totalSplitAmount: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var numSplitLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func calculateTip(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if let billAmount = Double(billAmountField.text!) {
            var tipPercentage = 0.0
            var split = 1.0

            switch tipSelector.selectedSegmentIndex {
            case 0:
                tipPercentage = 0.15
            case 1:
                tipPercentage = 0.18
            case 2:
                tipPercentage = 0.20
            case 3:
                userTipAmountField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            if let userTipAmount = Double(userTipAmountField.text!){
                    tipPercentage = userTipAmount / 100
                }
            default:
                break
            }

            switch userSplitSelector.selectedSegmentIndex {
            case 0:
                if split >= 2 {
                    split -= 1
                }
                let splitString = String(split)
                numSplitLabel.text = splitString
            case 1:
                split += 1
                let splitString = String(split)
                numSplitLabel.text = splitString
            default:
                break
            }


            let roundedBillAmount = round(100 * billAmount) / 100
            let tipAmount = roundedBillAmount * tipPercentage
            let roundedTipAmount = round(100*tipAmount)/100
            let totalAmount = roundedBillAmount + roundedTipAmount
            let totalSplitAmt = totalAmount / split

            if (!billAmountField.isEditing) {
                billAmountField.text = String(format: "%.2f", roundedBillAmount)
            }
            tipAmountField.text = String(format: "%.2f", roundedTipAmount)
            totalAmountField.text = String(format: "%.2f", totalAmount)
            totalSplitAmount.text = String(format: "%.2f", totalSplitAmt)


        } else {
            //show error
            billAmountField.text = ""
            tipAmountField.text = ""
            totalAmountField.text = ""
            totalSplitAmount.text = ""
            }
        }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
}
```

I'm doing this project in a Virtual Machine if that matters.

[Here is my Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKJXl.png)

Any suggestions on a fix would be much appreciated!

Comment: "Crashing" and "just gives me a white screen and no runtime errors" are two conflicting statements. Please [edit] your question and clarify which it is. Is it crashing or is it running but not showing anything?

Comment: also, Swift's latest version is 5. we have years before 10 comes out!

Comment: You are actually facing UI issue not a crash correct you statements and also attach the screen shot of result you are getting after run.

Comment: I fixed the problem. It was caused by a constraint issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your given controller from inspector to be initial controller. And check if the problem consists.

And have you given any constraints to the view ?

Second and most important thing there is no Swift 10. the latest version of Swift is 5.0! Please read basics first before developing.